# cannot get anything from dataimporter.request on updating index

Tags: solr, data-importer, delta-index

I'm quite new in SOLR, I have a question regarding the request for data importer.

In my `data-config.xml`, i have something like this

```
<entity name="content" pk="id" query="SELECT * FROM tableX"
    deltaQuery="SELECT max(id) AS id from ${dataimporter.request.dataView}"
    deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE ${dataimporter.delta.id} &lt; id">
....
</entity>
```

However, everytime I execute delta-import (`/dataimport?command=delta-import`), it always gives me exception like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
    org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: 
Unable to execute query: 
    SELECT max(id) AS id FROM  Processing Document # 1
```

I believe this error exists because the system didn't recognize `${dataimporter.request.dataView}`, but I don't know how to make that recognized?

Comment: Are you specifying the dataView parameter in the URL you're calling it with?

Comment: no I didnt... so I should specify it how exactly? like `...&dataView=tableX`?

Comment: Yes, AFAIK, that is how you do it.

Comment: well I thought it was generated so I could get the last id that has indexed :( anyway, your comment was worth an answer